# ESXi 5.0 can't parse crontab (ghettoVCB)

Tags: vmware-esxi, cron

I'm trying to run ghettoVCB via cron on a ESXi 5.0 Machine.

This is the command (add some linebreaks for better readability)

```
/vmfs/volumes/VMs\ Pool/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB.sh 
-f /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/vms_to_backup 
-g /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB.conf 
> /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB-backup-$(date +\%s).log
```

Executing the command did exactly what it should but when I add it to crontab, syslog spit out the following:

```
2013-05-26T09:32:01Z crond[1481072]: failed user root parsing 1-7 /vmfs/volumes/VMs\ Pool/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB.sh -f /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/vms_to_backup -g /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB.conf > /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB-backup-$(date +\%s).log
```

And here's the entry of the crontab:

```
0    0    *   *   1-7 /vmfs/volumes/VMs\ Pool/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB.sh -f /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/vms_to_backup -g /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB.conf > /vmfs/volumes/4e5b4f96-ebf53b38-db36-bc305bd75982/ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB-backup-$(date +\%s).log
```

Has anyone an idea why crond can't parse the command?

Answer (score 0):

Thumb Question - Simple Answer: Cron-Count starts with 0 - so

```
0    0    *   *   0-6
```

solves the problem